# Google Analytics on React JS site outputting incorrect data (broken sessions?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a site with most of the content managed by Wordpress, however when the user navigates to search pages (user searches for a product), it's handled by React JS.

It's all on the same domain, so the user never knows that they are interfacing with two different applications.

Google Analytics on the site, however, doesn't seem to perceive sessions correctly. It's logging entrances (landing pages) to the site as search pages with rather long URLs:

[image: landing pages]

- There are thousands of landing pages like this, and the site is new, so there's no way this is all traffic is coming in from external links
- Referrer path for all of these sessions is "(not set)"
- Internal IP addresses are filtered
- The traffic is coming from various sources/mediums, suggesting that sessions are somehow breaking (screenshot below)

[image: sources for landing pages]

Currently, GA is set up with GTM. I tried [using this](https://github.com/holidaycheck/react-google-tag-manager) to fire the GTM tag in React.

Also attempted making the GA tag within GTM fire on browser history changes rather than page views (history changes fire when in React, normal page views in Wordpress). But the issue still persists with these modifications.

*Note that these sessions are not specific to any one browser:*
[image: landing pages by browser]

Comment: Are these broken session coming from various browsers? I'm testing with chrome on windows and the analytics calls look correct.

Comment: I just added another screenshot below for browsers (issue doesn't seem to be browser or device-specific at all)

Comment: Is it possible that these are actually the entrance pages for these sessions? The users could be bookmarking the searches and coming back later or sharing search URLs with friends. What percent of entrances are coming from the `/search/` path?

Comment: 15.6% of landing pages go to the ReactJS url's (mostly /search) with long strings of variables at the end.

It's unlikely that people are bookmarking/sharing pages (the site is very new), but I thought it was possible too. 

Then I checked the source/medium (see 2nd screenshot): there are direct, organic and paid sources for these landing pages. We're not running any ad campaigns to /search URLs (_only_ to Unbounce landing pages that look like carjojo.com/crv-deals-carjojo/). Therefore something must be wrong with the sessions themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing comes from the fact upon search, you are switching your entry point and doing a hard refresh of your page to the React app. Even though the domain doesn't seem to change, it's still considered by the browser as a fresh page load and thus showing like so in your analytics, as shown by this request:

[image: request]

You haven't really told if you were using react-router in your app (I'm assuming you are given the different paths), a way to get around the problem would be to use [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) instead of the default GA script and leverage the `onUpdate` callback of react-router.

First import and initialize the module with your GA id:

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01')
```

Then in your routes configuration, add the `onUpdate` property on the `<Router>` and create a method that will call the google analytics with only the pathname so you won't end up with all the query parameters that are quite obnoxious in the dashboard.

```js
const onUpdate = () => {
  ReactGA.set({ page: window.location.pathname })
  ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname)
}

<Router onUpdate={onUpdate}>
  ...
</Router>
```

Still, if you want to keep track of the user search, I would recommend using events instead, and doing something like the following upon search:

```js
ReactGA.event({
  category: 'User',
  action: 'Search',
  value: 'your formatted search value'
})
```

It will also give you the ability to format the value of the search any way you want, which would be more readable for you than query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this. If we strip our the query parameters though, we won't be able to track site search, right?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to track the search, I would say using GA events would be a better approach, and won't burst your location view, will add this to the answer.

Comment: Interesting, will try this. React also runs other pages with query parameters (not just `search` but also our shopping cart functionality `cart` and product view `drilldown`), so I guess events should be set up for these as well.

Comment: If you need to track these info, yes sure!

Comment: @Orun Any other particular concerns you're having?